# Why does laravel image upload show incorrect url in view?

Tags: php, post, laravel, upload

I have a form that uploads an image file to a post, very simply and it uses image intervention

`"intervention/image": "dev-master"`

so I can resize it etc but at the moment its a simple post action like so:

```
<?php namespace Boroughcc\Http\Controllers;

use Input;
use Redirect;
use Storage;
use SirTrevorJs;
use STConverter;
use Validator;
use Image;
use Boroughcc\Post;
use Boroughcc\Http\Requests;
use Boroughcc\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostsController extends Controller {

public function store()
    {
        // image upload function

        // $img = Image::make(Input::file('featured_image'));
        // dd($img);

        $input = Input::all();
        $validation = Validator::make($input, Post::$rules);
        $entry = array(
            'title' => Input::get('title'),
            'featured_image' => Input::file('featured_image')        
        );
        if ($validation->passes())
        {
            $img = Image::make(Input::file('featured_image'));

            $pathinfo = pathinfo($img);
            $type = $pathinfo['basename'];
            $filename = date('Y-m-d-H:i:s').$type;
            $path = 'img/posts/' . $filename;
            $img->save($path);
            $post = Post::create(
                $entry
            );
            return Redirect::route('posts.index')->with('message', 'Post created');
        } else {
                return Redirect::route('posts.create')
                ->withInput()
                ->withErrors($validation)
                ->with('message', 'There were validation errors.');
        }

        //Post::create( $input );

        // return Redirect::route('posts.index')->with('message', 'Post created');


    }
```

The post checks for validations and if all are correct it sends the post to save it and should hopefully generate the file. When it saves it the file goes into my `/public/img/posts/` folder fine. here is the post model below;

Post.php

```
<?php namespace Boroughcc;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model {

    //
    protected $guarded = [];

    public static $rules = array(
        'title' => 'required',
        'featured_image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,bmp,gif,svg'
    );

}
```

So you can see what I am trying to output here is what I am using in the post.index page to output the image url here:

```
{!! Form::model(new Boroughcc\Post, ['route' => ['posts.store'], 'files' => true]) !!}
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('title', 'Title:') !!}
    {!! Form::text('title') !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <strong>Only edit this if necessary, this is auto populated</strong><br>
    {!! Form::label('slug', 'Slug:') !!}
    {!! Form::text('slug') !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('featured_image', 'Featured Image:') !!}
    {!! Form::file('featured_image') !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('body', 'Post body:') !!}
    {!! Form::textarea('body', null, array('id'=>'','class'=>'sir-trevor')) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::submit($submit_text, ['class'=>'btn primary']) !!}
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

When I go to get the file url to output I get this instead:

`"featured_image" => "/private/var/folders/mf/srx7jt8s2rdg0mn5hr98cvz80000gn/T/phpMEtuuA"`

This is what I get, is there something wrong with this and why is it rendering this only?

Comment: [http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#files] The object returned by the file method is an instance of the Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile class, which extends the PHP SplFileInfo class and provides a variety of methods for interacting with the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When uploading a file in Laravel, accessing it via the `Input::file` method will return an instance of `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile`, so assigning `'featured_image' => Input::file('featured_image')` would not work.

So instead of building the `$entry` details array before you save the file to disk, you should actually generate the image path and filename, and store that in the database. Also, unless you want to resize or manipulate the image in any way, there's no need to use the **Intervention** library. This should do just fine:

```
// Get the uploaded file object
$image = Input::file('featured_image');

// Generate the necessary file details
$extension = pathinfo($image->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$filename = date('Y-m-d-H:i:s') . '.' . $extension;
$path = 'img/posts/';

// Move the uploaded image to the specified path
// using the generated specified filename
$image->move($path, $filename);

// Save the post to the database
// using the path and filename use above
$post = Post::create(array(
    'title' => Input::get('title'),
    'featured_image' => $path . $filename
));
```

Comment: just a quick one, how can I get the extension on the end of the file for example .png? I have tried `$type = pathinfo($img, PATHINFO_BASENAME);` and then done `$filename = date('Y-m-d-H:i:s') . $extension . $type;` but it still returns blank

Comment: There was an error in my answer. To extract the extension the code should have been `$extension = pathinfo($image->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`. Also the filename should include the `.` manually as `pathinfo` returns the extension without the dot in it. I've updated the code in my answer.